# Using both Lazy Load and Auto Image Alt and Title Changer scripts at the same time in Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, blogger

I have a blog http://www.rawdevart.com/
I have already installed a script for automatically changing `alt` and `title` of all the images in the post loaded.
The script I am using is as follows :

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.homepageUrl!=data:blog.url'>
 <script type='text/javascript'>  


 //<![CDATA[  
 $(document).ready(function() {  
  $('img').each(function(){  
   var $img = $(this);  
   var filename = $img.attr('src')  
   var returnt=filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));

      var ctitle=returnt.replace(/%2B|_/g, " ").replace(/%2521|_/g,"!");

if((returnt=="if_go-previous_118774")||(returnt=="if_go-next_118773"))
   {
    if(returnt=="if_go-previous_118774")
      {
        $img.attr('title', "Previous Chapter");
        $img.attr('alt' ,"Previous Chapter");
      }
   else if(returnt=="if_go-next_118773")
      {
        $img.attr('title', "Next Chapter");
        $img.attr('alt' ,"Next Chapter");
      }
   else if(returnt=="ch-list")
      {
        $img.attr('title', "Chapter List");
        $img.attr('alt' ,"Chapter List");
      }
   }else{
   ctitle=getTitle+" Page "+ctitle;
   $img.attr('title', ctitle);
   $img.attr('alt' ,ctitle);
   }  
  });  
 }); 

 //]]>
```

I had some pics that I wanted it to be renamed with particular values so I added a lot of if's in there.

And here is the LazyLoad Images Script I found on the internet which was told that can be used in Blogger.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
(function(a){a.fn.lazyload=function(b){var c={threshold:0,failurelimit:0,event:"scroll",effect:"show",container:window};if(b){a.extend(c,b)}var d=this;if("scroll"==c.event){a(c.container).bind("scroll",function(b){var e=0;d.each(function(){if(a.abovethetop(this,c)||a.leftofbegin(this,c)){}else if(!a.belowthefold(this,c)&&!a.rightoffold(this,c)){a(this).trigger("appear")}else{if(e++>c.failurelimit){return false}}});var f=a.grep(d,function(a){return!a.loaded});d=a(f)})}this.each(function(){var b=this;if(undefined==a(b).attr("original")){a(b).attr("original",a(b).attr("src"))}if("scroll"!=c.event||undefined==a(b).attr("src")||c.placeholder==a(b).attr("src")||a.abovethetop(b,c)||a.leftofbegin(b,c)||a.belowthefold(b,c)||a.rightoffold(b,c)){if(c.placeholder){a(b).attr("src",c.placeholder)}else{a(b).removeAttr("src")}b.loaded=false}else{b.loaded=true}a(b).one("appear",function(){if(!this.loaded){a("<img />").bind("load",function(){a(b).hide().attr("src",a(b).attr("original"))[c.effect](c.effectspeed);b.loaded=true}).attr("src",a(b).attr("original"))}});if("scroll"!=c.event){a(b).bind(c.event,function(c){if(!b.loaded){a(b).trigger("appear")}})}});a(c.container).trigger(c.event);return this};a.belowthefold=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).height()+a(window).scrollTop()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().top+a(c.container).height()}return d<=a(b).offset().top-c.threshold};a.rightoffold=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).width()+a(window).scrollLeft()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().left+a(c.container).width()}return d<=a(b).offset().left-c.threshold};a.abovethetop=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).scrollTop()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().top}return d>=a(b).offset().top+c.threshold+a(b).height()};a.leftofbegin=function(b,c){if(c.container===undefined||c.container===window){var d=a(window).scrollLeft()}else{var d=a(c.container).offset().left}return d>=a(b).offset().left+c.threshold+a(b).width()};a.extend(a.expr[":"],{"below-the-fold":"$.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})","above-the-fold":"!$.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})","right-of-fold":"$.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})","left-of-fold":"!$.rightoffold(a, {threshold : 0, container: window})"})})(jQuery);$(function(){$("img").lazyload({placeholder:"http://i22.servimg.com/u/f22/15/42/72/40/grey10.gif",effect:"fadeIn",threshold:"-50"})})//]]></script>
```

In the above Lazy Load script there is a particular part that is giving me problem : 
`placeholder:"http://i22.servimg.com/u/f22/15/42/72/40/grey10.gif"`.

The use of this part of the script is making all the images `alt` and `title` values to become like `*Title of the chapter* grey10`.

By the way, the variable `getTitle` is used for getting the name of the chapter.

And here is an example of the problem I am facing :

Suppose in this link : http://www.rawdevart.com/2017/09/legend-chapter-6-raw-manga.html

When you move your mouse over an image you can see the `alt` like this of the second image : `Legend Chapter 6 Raw Manga Page 002`

002 is the image link's last characters `URL/002.jpeg` which is being processed through the script and is being made to 002 only and then added with getTitle.

But after using Lazy Load, the `alt` is becoming as `Legend Chapter 6 Raw Manga Page grey10`

As I see how to logic is working, when the page is loaded, the first image is loaded untouched and the second image is being replaced by the placeholder gif file. Then when we move down the gif image is being replaced with the original. But by doing this, the alt and title how I want are not acquired.

**So is there a way to use both scripts without losing any functionality? Please help.**

BTW, you can put anything in the link `http://i22.servimg.com/u/f22/15/42/72/40/grey10.gif`, replace grey10 with any letters like `http://i22.servimg.com/u/f22/15/42/72/40/anyshit.gif` and still, it gives a 1x1 resolution image. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the problem is that the wrong Image URL being chosen when using the Lazy load script. We can check if the `original` attribute is present in the image element (which always contains the correct Image URL) and use that for assigning the `title` and `alt` attributes. In the script change the line -

```
var filename = $img.attr('src');
```

to -

```
if($img.attr('original')){
    var filename = $img.attr('original');
} else {
    var filename = $img.attr('src');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know exactly what is happening without seeing your HTML, but if that image is causing problems, simply skip it in your processing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('img').each(function(){  
        var $img = $(this);  
        var filename = $img.attr('src')  
        var returnt=filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
        var ctitle=returnt.replace(/%2B|_/g, " ").replace(/%2521|_/g,"!");

        // If this is the file causing problems, skip over it and continue
        // with the next image.
        if (filename === 'http://i22.servimg.com/u/f22/15/42/72/40/grey10.gif') {
            continue;
        }

        // ... etc, rest of your code
```

If there are more than one placholder images in the lazy loading script causing problems, and they are hosted on the same server, and none of the images you *want* to process are on that server, maybe skipping based on the URL would make more sense:

```
if (filename.indexOf('servimg.com') >= 0) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: No, not working. You can see as an example in this :
http://www.rawdevart.com/2017/09/legend-chapter-6-raw-manga.html
When you move your mouse on an image you can see the alt of it. The alt and title value is `*Title of the Chapter* *IMAGE NAME* `  
Example `Legend Chapter 6 Raw Manga Page 001`
Here : 001 is the URL ending or the image name as I uploaded it (001.jpeg)
After being processed through the scripts its being put as only 001 adding with the title of the chapter.
But when using the Lazy Load, it becomes something like this 
`Legend Chapter 6 Raw Manga Page grey10`

Comment: @yashas123 I don't follow.  Taking a concrete example, the first image on the page you link to has title "Legend Chapter 6 Raw Manga Page 001".  AFAICT that is correct, according to your code.  That's the title that the last few lines will generate (`ctitle=getTitle+" Page "+ctitle;`, etc).  So what is the problem?

Comment: FYI there are 3 errors shown on the console loading that page.  Maybe you could try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - a small chunk of static html, with only the JS we are talking about, that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @yashas123 Though if you are still seeing the problem in that first title, but I am not, then it sounds like the fix works, but you still have the old, unfixed Javascript cached, so you're not seeing it.  Try hitting shift-reload, using an incognito tab, clearing cache etc.

Comment: @yashas123, did this help? Your site now seems OK AFAICT.

Comment: Please try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and post that HTML and JS in your question - minimal means without any other JS, just 1 image, super simple.